# She doesn't want to make milk for me

Tags: word-usage

"I want to drink milk." he asked his mother.

His mother refused to make a milk for him because he was naughty.

He came to me,

> "She doesn't want to **make milk** for me."

What word should be use if he wanted his mother to make a bottle for himself?

Can I use "make milk"?

Comment: If you're lactating, you can make milk. If not, I'd avoid that expression.

Comment: What's other word can be use?

Comment: If you're talking about a bottle, and the child asks for that, say that the child wants a bottle but the mom won't give him one.

Comment: She won't *give me milk* or *give me a bottle of milk*, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Make" implies that there is some amount of work to put in to creating/producing the item. For example, you could make a milkshake. This means you are making a milkshake from the basic ingredients, turning milk, sugar and flavouring into a milkshake. However it was the cow who made the milk. Saying "she doesn't want to make milk for me" means she doesn't want to produce the milk - with her breast!

An English speaker is likely to say `she didn't want to pour me a glass of milk` rather than "make". Or simply `she didn't want to give me milk`.

Comment: That's a milk powder.